# Change TimePicker text color

Tags: android, xml

I've been trying to change the textcolor of my timepicker. But I can't find where the parent style is located. I've tried both

```
<style name="MyTimePicker" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.TimePicker">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text</item>
</style>
```

and

```
<style name="MyTimePicker" parent="@android:style/Widget.TimePicker">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text</item>
</style>
```

My `minSdkVersion` is 15. My `targetSdkVersion` is 20. I have rebuilded and cleaned my project.
I think I've been through every similar question on SO and none of them really have provided a solution for me. The only answer that might work is using some sort of library, but I'm not a big fan of that solution. Is the path to the parent something different from what I'm using, because I'm pretty sure I should be able to access it somehow?

**Edit**
This is how the theme is applied;

```
<TimePicker
    style="@style/MyTimePicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/timePicker"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

On a note this is the error I receive (forgot to place it before):

> Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.Holo.TimePicker'.

**Edit 2**
A couple of the questions I've viewed to try to solve this:

1. [How can I override TimePicker to change text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969513/how-can-i-override-timepicker-to-change-text-color) - I think this question gets as close to an answer, but I'm not entirely sure what I need to do? Do I need to import the android TimePicker style into my project?
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24973586/set-textcolor-for-timepicker-in-customized-app-theme - No answer is given.
3. [How can i change the textcolor of my timepicker and datepicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227884/how-can-i-change-the-textcolor-of-my-timepicker-and-datepicker) - Tried the 0 votes answer, but it didn't work.
4. [How to change the default color of DatePicker and TimePicker dialog in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077530/how-to-change-the-default-color-of-datepicker-and-timepicker-dialog-in-android) - Again can't find the TimePicker in a similar way.
5. [Android - How do I change the textColor in a TimePicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662544/android-how-do-i-change-the-textcolor-in-a-timepicker) - Again, can't find the actual TimePicker parent.

These are probably the best questions/answers to my problem, but none of them help me. It would be nice to get a definitive answer on this.

Comment: the first style should work,  how did you applied that style?

Comment: Tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21361885/3249477)?

Comment: @user3249477 Yes I tried that/those too. Non of them work, because the TimePicker cannot be found (I can find things such as actionbar etc.). I _can_ find the styles in android styles.xml, but I can't access them (the TimePicker specifically)

Comment: I have already answered this question, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962075/change-the-text-color-of-numberpicker/22962195#22962195

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I have combined [Paul Burke's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26075751/1294864) and [Simon's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22962195/1294864) to succesfully edit the text colour of the `TimePicker`.

Here's how it is accomplished:

```java
TimePicker time_picker; //Instantiated in onCreate()
Resources system;

private void set_timepicker_text_colour(){
    system = Resources.getSystem();
    int hour_numberpicker_id = system.getIdentifier("hour", "id", "android");
    int minute_numberpicker_id = system.getIdentifier("minute", "id", "android");
    int ampm_numberpicker_id = system.getIdentifier("amPm", "id", "android");

    NumberPicker hour_numberpicker = (NumberPicker) time_picker.findViewById(hour_numberpicker_id);
    NumberPicker minute_numberpicker = (NumberPicker) time_picker.findViewById(minute_numberpicker_id);
    NumberPicker ampm_numberpicker = (NumberPicker) time_picker.findViewById(ampm_numberpicker_id);

    set_numberpicker_text_colour(hour_numberpicker);
    set_numberpicker_text_colour(minute_numberpicker);
    set_numberpicker_text_colour(ampm_numberpicker);
}

private void set_numberpicker_text_colour(NumberPicker number_picker){
    final int count = number_picker.getChildCount();
    final int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.text);

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        View child = number_picker.getChildAt(i);

        try{
            Field wheelpaint_field = number_picker.getClass().getDeclaredField("mSelectorWheelPaint");
            wheelpaint_field.setAccessible(true);

            ((Paint)wheelpaint_field.get(number_picker)).setColor(color);
            ((EditText)child).setTextColor(color);
            number_picker.invalidate();
        }
        catch(NoSuchFieldException e){
            Log.w("setNumberPickerTextColor", e);
        }
        catch(IllegalAccessException e){
            Log.w("setNumberPickerTextColor", e);
        }
        catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
            Log.w("setNumberPickerTextColor", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that this answer might be outdated by now. I ran into this a while ago with something that might have been buggy (see my question for more details). Otherwise you should probably follow Vikram's answer.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.NumberPicker.getChildCount()' on a null object reference.                         final int count = number_picker.getChildCount();

Comment: @voidpointer if you have another question please use the "ask question" button on the top right of your screen. What you have is a plain null pointer exception.

Comment: @Bono This code is not work in android Lollipop..  hour_numberpicker ya other all is given by null only for Android Lollipop..

Comment: @Bono Tried the same thing for changing text size. But when we scroll to change the time, the size changes to the original size.

Comment: Note that this answer may be outdated currently.

Comment: Since API 29 there is setTextColor() function for NumberPicker, so no need work this around.

Answer (score 9):

Not sure why you would need to dive into Java Reflection API for this. Its a simple styling matter. The attribute that you need to override is: `textColorPrimary`.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    ....
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ff0000</item>
</style>
```

If you're using the `TimePicker` inside a `Dialog`, override `android:textColorPrimary` in the dialog's theme.

That's about it.

Comment: The problem is it couldn't find the `Theme.Holo.Light` parent.  That's  why the text color couldn't be changed. Unfortunately your answer is about something a bit different. I'll look to editing my question soon to portray this.

Comment: @Bono Not sure why it can't find `Theme.Holo.Light`. But the parent is irrelevant here. You should keep the parent as whatever you are already using, most probably `Theme.AppCompat[.Light]`.

Comment: @Bono A bit more info: the `attr` that supplies the text color for `TimePicker` is `textColorPrimary`. So, we can change the text color by overriding this attr as above. BUT, this attr is also used as the default text color for all `TextViews`. Meaning, if you _don't supply an `android:textColor="@color/some_color"`_, it will use `textColorPrimary`. The easiest way to go about this is to create the `TimePicker` in java using a `ContextThemeWrapper`. Seeing that this question is quite old, I appreciate your comment. Do let me know if you need a working example using `ContextThemeWrapper`.

Answer (score 6):

Adding to [Vikram](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29315006/6478047) answer , Set the theme to timePicker do not set it as style

in `styles.xml`

```
 <style name="timePickerOrange">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/orange</item> <!-- color for digits -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/orange</item> <!-- color for colon -->
    <item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/orange</item> <!-- color for (horizontal) delimeters -->
</style>
```

and for timePicker

```
<TimePicker
    android:theme="@style/timePickerOrange"
    android:id="@+id/timePicker_defaultTime"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/hero_regular"
    android:timePickerMode="spinner"
    app:fontFamily="@font/hero_regular" />
```

Comment: This doesnt work.

Answer (score 4):

A `TimePicker` is really just two `NumberPicker`s. Looking into the `Widget.NumberPicker` style and layout, you'll find the it uses

```
@style/TextAppearance.Large.Inverse.NumberPickerInputText
```

Unfortunately, `TextAppearance.Large.Inverse.NumberPickerInputText` doesn't use one of the attributes that you can set in your theme. So you have two options:

1. Copy the necessary classes to make your own version of `NumberPicker` and `TimePicker`. (You might be able to extract something from libraries like [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere))
2. Use hacks.

If you want to go the second route, you can do this:

```
private int mNumberPickerInputId = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Resources system = Resources.getSystem();

    // This is the internal id of the EditText used in NumberPicker (hack)
    mNumberPickerInputId = 
        system.getIdentifier("numberpicker_input", "id", "android");

    // just used for full example, use your TimePicker
    TimePicker timePicker = new TimePicker(this);
    setContentView(timePicker);

    final int hourSpinnerId = 
        system.getIdentifier("hour", "id", "android");
    View hourSpinner = timePicker.findViewById(hourSpinnerId);
    if (hourSpinner != null) {
        setNumberPickerTextColor(hourSpinner, Color.BLUE);
    }

    final int minSpinnerId = 
        system.getIdentifier("minute", "id", "android");
    View minSpinner = timePicker.findViewById(minSpinnerId);
    if (minSpinner != null) {
        setNumberPickerTextColor(minSpinner, Color.BLUE);
    }

    final int amPmSpinnerId = 
        system.getIdentifier("amPm", "id", "android");
    View amPmSpinner = timePicker.findViewById(amPmSpinnerId);
    if (amPmSpinner != null) {
        setNumberPickerTextColor(amPmSpinner, Color.BLUE);
    }
}

private void setNumberPickerTextColor(View spinner, int color) {
    TextView input = (TextView) spinner.findViewById(mNumberPickerInputId);
    input.setTextColor(color);
}
```

**EDIT**

Upon further investigation, this hack doesn't really work well. It won't allow you to change the color of the `NumberPicker` above/below values. The color also resets after the use interacts with it. It seems that your only option will be to create your own copies of the necessary classes (option #1 above).

Comment: Thanks Paul the "hack" looks fine to me. I have a couple of questions though; How do I get the numbers above and below to change colours as well? And when I rotate/change the spinners (to pick a different number) they default back to black again. How do I prevent this?

Comment: @Bono Please see my updated answer. Looks like option 1 may be the only way to properly control this. :-(

Answer (score 2):

@Vikram is right
This is so simple.You can try this way

```
<style name="abirStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set **android:textColorPrimaryInverse** and **android:textColorSecondaryInverse**. That should do the job without using Reflection.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">@color/colorLightGrey</item>
</style>
```

Comment: That's what I needed

Answer (score 0):

For those using the spinner, this is an easy way to change the colors and even provides the appropriate shadow effect of the previous and next numbers. Spinner requires a theme because most of the default xml attributes for colors only effect the clock mode.

**styles.xml**

```
  <style name="timepicker">
       <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white </item>
       <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white </item>

    </style>
```

**xml layout file**

```
 <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/timepicker"
        android:layout_below="@id/line1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:timePickerMode="spinner" />
```