# Change color of TimePicker (RadialTimePickerView)?

Tags: java, android, colors, timepicker

How do I change the number/picker-color of the TimePicker/RadialTimePickerView? I can see, that the RadialTimePickerView sets its color internal by using

```
final int numbersTextColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.TimePicker_numbersTextColor,
            res.getColor(R.color.timepicker_default_text_color_material));
```

I tried adding a `timepicker_default_text_color_material` item to the colors.xml, but this didn't work out.

The black numbers and the blue picker should be white:
[image: The black numbers and the blue picker should be white.]

Comment: try this link may help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015798/change-timepicker-text-color

Comment: Doesnt help me. I cant set these several color names in my app theme. They wont be recognized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

More or less, as Saket commented, I need to append my styles.xml:

```
<style name="myTimePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.TimePicker">
    <item name="android:numbersTextColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:numbersBackgroundColor">@color/timepicker_header</item>
    <item name="android:numbersSelectorColor">#88000000</item>
    <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/timepicker_header</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:timePickerDialogTheme">@style/myTimePickerDialogStyle</item>
</style>
```

Comment: is it possible to chance with Java, instead of using an xml files?