# How to make the TimePicker with spinner mode as the custom layout(not with the clock mode)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-timepicker

[image]

I want to make such layout with the color of the SelectedText should be orange or green of TimePicker of mode type spinner. How can i do this please help me.

```
 <TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/timePicker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content
    android:timePickerMode="spinner"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout2"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">
```

Comment: dnt understand what you need ?

Comment: https://github.com/brucetoo/PickView

Comment: I want to highlight the selected Time?

Comment: now what you want from us ?

Comment: You can get reference from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32549992/how-to-customize-timepicker-in-material-design-android

Comment: I have done with the UI part of TimePicker in spinner mode, but i want the selected time color to be changed, please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change color of TimePicker (RadialTimePickerView)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31360520/change-color-of-timepicker-radialtimepickerview)

Answer (score -1):

Pls change mode into spinner in layout with timepicker