# How to change color of TimePickerAndroid in React Native?

Tags: timepicker, react-native

Is it possible to change default color of the TimePickerAndroid component ?

[image]

Comment: If you use Expo, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/77703362/4350421

Answer (score 16):

You would have to change it from the styles.xml file of android. Here's what you do:

1) Open up styles.xml: "android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml"
2) you'll need to add a few lines:

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:timePickerDialogTheme">@style/Dialog.Theme</item>
</style>

<style name="Dialog.Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#0000FF</item>
</style>
```

In styles.xml you should already have:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

If you do just add the remaining lines. If not go ahead and add them.

4) Lastly, just recompile the app. "react-native run-android". You should see the color change right away.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It should be marked as such.

Comment: This worked for me -- give this answer the checkmark.

Comment: In case of date picker dialogue <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/Dialog.Theme</item>

Answer (score 1):

Using React-native, unfortunately no.

However, by changing some java files in RN and using [this solution from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015798/change-timepicker-text-color) you might be able to do it. 
If you succeed doing this, I suggest you create a Pull Request on RN's repository as it might be very useful for other users. 
You could also develop it as a module and open source via NPM.