# Expo: Change accent color of @react-native-community/datetimepicker

Tags: react-native, datepicker, expo

I am working on a managed Expo project (Expo SDK version 49). I use `@react-native-community/datetimepicker` to display a date picker dialog:

```js
import { View } from "react-native";
import RNDateTimePicker from "@react-native-community/datetimepicker";


const DatePickerTest = () => {
        const value = new Date();
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                <RNDateTimePicker
                    mode="date"
                    value={value}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
;

export default DatePickerTest;
```

When I run the code on Android, a [Date Picker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker) is rendered with a header and selection color inherited from Android's default theme (green, in my case):

[image: date picker green background]

I understand that in order to change the accent color, I need to change `styles.xml` in `android/app/src/main/res/values` (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48369871/4350421). However, in an Expo managed project, I do not have access to the `android` folder.

**How can I change the accent color without ejecting from Expo?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the introduction of [config plugins](https://docs.expo.dev/config-plugins/introduction/) in SDK Verion 41, it is possible to interact with the Android configuration files at build time without ejecting from the Expo managed workflow. Note that this approach won't work with Expo Go - you will need to build a [custom dev client](https://docs.expo.dev/development/introduction/).

I have posted a detailed description of the generic approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70775576/4350421).

In order to change the accent color:

1. Create a `plugins` directory at the root of your project.
2. Create a file named `custom-android-styles.js` in this directory, with the following code:

```js
const { withAndroidStyles } = require('@expo/config-plugins');

const withCustomStyles = config => {
    return withAndroidStyles(config, async config => {
        config.modResults = applyCustomStyles(config.modResults);
        return config;
    });
};

function applyCustomStyles(styles) {
    // Add items to the App Theme
    const appTheme = styles.resources.style.find(style => style.$.name === 'AppTheme');
    if (appTheme) {
        appTheme.item.push({ _: '@style/Dialog.Theme', $: { name: 'android:datePickerDialogTheme' } });
        appTheme.item.push({ _: '@style/Dialog.Theme', $: { name: 'android:timePickerDialogTheme' } });
    }

    // Add new style definition
    styles.resources.style.push({
        $: { name: 'Dialog.Theme', parent: 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog' },
        item: [{ _: '#a7243a', $: { name: 'colorAccent' } }],
    });

    return styles;
}

module.exports = withCustomStyles;
```

3. Add the following to `app.config.js`:

```js
export default {
    expo: {
    //...
        plugins: [
            //...
            "./plugins/custom-android-styles.js",
        ]
    }
};
```

4. Build your custom dev client with EAS.

If all goes well, your DatePicker will look like this:

[image]

Comment: just wanted to let you know you've made my day - thank you!

Comment: Does this solution work locally?

Comment: Yes, if you use local builds: https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/local-builds/