# is there any way to change text colors of time picker at runtime?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-timepicker

i am trying to implement multiple themes in android and i want to change text colors of time picker programatically according to selected theme.

By using theme property in xml we can easily set a style to time picker but in my case i want to do it programatically.

android:theme="@style/timePickerPurple".

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015798/change-timepicker-text-color

Comment: @KudzaiMutsvairo i have used a few solutions from this reference but its not working properly.